# Gradle Build failed Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, gradle

trying to build for android 30 using unity 2019.4.26f1, followed this link :https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/android-11-build

Error:
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin\java.exe -classpath "D:\gradle-5.6.4\lib\gradle-launcher-5.6.4.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.

> 1 exception was raised by workers:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.IconCompatParcelizer found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat$1 found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat$OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat$PermissionCompatDelegate found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat$RequestPermissionsRequestCodeValidator found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat$SharedElementCallback21Impl found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat$SharedElementCallback21Impl$1 found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ActivityManagerCompat found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ActivityOptionsCompat found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ActivityOptionsCompat$ActivityOptionsCompatImpl found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.AlarmManagerCompat found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.AppComponentFactory found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.AppLaunchChecker found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.AppOpsManagerCompat found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.BundleCompat found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.BundleCompat$BundleCompatBaseImpl found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity$ExtraData found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory$CompatWrapped found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.FrameMetricsAggregator found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.FrameMetricsAggregator$FrameMetricsApi24Impl found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.FrameMetricsAggregator$FrameMetricsApi24Impl$1 found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.FrameMetricsAggregator$FrameMetricsBaseImpl found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.FrameMetricsAggregator$MetricType found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.JobIntentService found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$CompatJobEngine found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$CompatWorkEnqueuer found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$CompatWorkItem found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$GenericWorkItem found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$JobServiceEngineImpl found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$JobServiceEngineImpl$WrapperWorkItem found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$JobWorkEnqueuer found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$WorkEnqueuer found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NavUtils found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationBuilderWithBuilderAccessor found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$Action found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$Action$Builder found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$Action$Extender found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$Action$SemanticAction found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$Action$WearableExtender found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$BadgeIconType found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$BigPictureStyle found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$BigTextStyle found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$Builder found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$CarExtender found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$CarExtender$UnreadConversation found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$CarExtender$UnreadConversation$Builder found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$DecoratedCustomViewStyle found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$Extender found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$GroupAlertBehavior found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$InboxStyle found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$MessagingStyle found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$MessagingStyle$Message found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$NotificationVisibility found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$StreamType found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$Style found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$WearableExtender found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompatBuilder found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompatExtras found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompatJellybean found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompatSideChannelService found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompatSideChannelService$NotificationSideChannelStub found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat$CancelTask found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat$NotifyTask found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat$ServiceConnectedEvent found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat$SideChannelManager found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat$SideChannelManager$ListenerRecord found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat$Task found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.Person found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.Person$Builder found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and jetified-core-1.0.0-rc02-runtime.jar (:core-1.0.0-rc02:)
> Duplicate class androidx.core.app.RemoteInput found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime

Answer (score 0):

It appears your external android asset library has duplicate files. In Unity try performing:

Assets => External Dependency Manager => Android Resolver => Delete Resolved Libraries

Comment: tried this but still the same errors are there

Answer (score 0):

Search the **core-1.0.0-rc02** on your assets and delete it. assuming you have google packages and you have this file, it's being conflicted each other. As your logs says it duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed that issue by deleting the **playcore.arr** file from the **Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.play.core/Runtime/Plugins** folder

[image]